# Create overview of Cucumber features using Maven

Tags: java, cucumber, cucumber-java

Is there a way using Maven to create an overview (must) and details (nice to have) as a clickable documentation set of all cucumber feature files in a project?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by "clickable" but you will get a full overview from the report that is generated by running a Cucumber test suite. You have two built in options for report generation, JSON and HTML format. You can configure that using your `@CucumberOptions` like this:

```
@CucumberOptions(features = {"..."}, format = {
        "json:target/cucumber-dev/cucumber.json", "pretty"}, ...)
```

or

```
@CucumberOptions(features = {"..."}, format = {
        "html:target/cucumber-dev/cucumber.html", "pretty"}, ...)
```